# How can I get chrome to prompt to save password in HTML form

Tags: html

I have a simple email/password HTML form that I would like chrome to prompt to save the password. I don't know why it won't ask for it. Here is the code:

```
 <form name="loginForm" action="">
        E-Mail:<br><input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="E-mail"/><br>
        Password:<br><input id="pwdInputBox" type="password" name="password" required/><br>
        <input id="loginFormSubmitButton" type="button" value="Login" onclick="loginFormHandler();"/>
 </form>
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 10):

Chrome prompts to save the password only if the server certificate has no issues.

Which certificates will not make the browser prompt to save the password:

- self-signed certificates
- default server certificate WMSVC installed in IIS
- certificates with expired date